# Finding another site in Wordpress Multisite by name?

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite, wpmu

Finding another site in Wordpress Multisite by name?

Let's say I have several different sites in a WPMU (WordPress Multisite). They are:

```
"Bill's Site": coolsite.com/bill
"Jim's Site": coolsite.com/jim
"Edna's Site": coolsite.com/Edna
Etc...
```

Now let's say that on Edna's site, there is a reference to Bill's Site, and I want to programmatically get the url to it. I have the NAME of the site (Bill's Site).

I tried using `get_sites():`

```
$args = array("search" => "Bill's Site");
$results = get_sites($args);
```

But that returned an empty array.

I also played around with `get_blog_details()`, which seems better since it actually claims to be able to search specifically by blog name, but it returned a made-up URL that didn't work... Basically, using it to search for "Bill's Site" returned `coolsite.com/bill%27s%20site`, when it SHOULD return coolsite.com/bill.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: I build a lot of WordPress multisites, and I have to say that I'm unclear of why this would be needed. Why would someone know someone else's site name without knowing their URL, too? Unless you have many sites (maybe 100+) I'd recommend just calling `get_sites()` and retrieving all sites. Site creation is usually not too common so both this call as well as the result of the lookup should be easily cached by you. A site's name is actual stored in the per-site `options` table and there's no real easy way to query for it, unfortunately.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not saying this is a bad idea, but it feels like trying to solve a problem that might be tackled in a better way. Almost every time that you have cross-site talks, or a site is "aware" that it is in a multisite in the first place, you end up with some extra work and edge cases. We definitely build MS sites that cross-talk, but that's always on a case-by-case basis and we always gauge whether it is worth the effort.

Comment: Ha, as I was writing the example, I could see how it would seem like an impossibly unnecessary situation to have site's name but not URL. It's a reverse engineering situation. Hundreds of sites on this, and in past years, there was an option where on certain sites, there was a field to enter the name of a certain related site. I now want to have those fields as links rather than text. But I think your allusion to periodically pulling everything and caching is probably the best bet. Thank you!